# No results found in query

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to modify a field for the the currentUser in Parse. I run the following code and my log keeps returning "no results found". I've logged the ObjectId for reference and verified that it's correct in my database.

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
          query.getInBackground(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId(), new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
              public void done(ParseUser object, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.i("objectId", userObjectId);
                    object.put("instructorId", instructorId.getText().toString());
                    object.saveEventually();
                } else {
                    Log.e("objectId", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    Log.i("objectId", userObjectId);
                }
              }
          });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption that the User class has the classname `User` is probably the issue. Try `_User`.

BUT, you should really be creating your query as

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
```

That way you don't even need to know the classname for the user object.

Comment: Exactly, User, Installation and a few other classes have their getQuery() method to avoid this kind of mess.

Comment: Thank you, I suspected it was something that obvious!